# HttpWebRequest does not retrieve the url I have set for

Tags: httpwebrequest

I am trying to download

"https://www.google.com/search?sclient=psy-ab&biw=1472&bih=740&espv=2&tbm=vid&btnG=Search&q=%25%25%25#q=iran&tbm=nws";

by the following code:

```
        string url = "https://www.google.com/search?sclient=psy-ab&biw=1472&bih=740&espv=2&tbm=vid&btnG=Search&q=%25%25%25#q=iran&tbm=nws";
        try
        {
            string htmlPage = "";

            //http request preparing
            CookieContainer CC = new CookieContainer();
            HttpWebRequest objRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            objRequest.Timeout = 60000;
            objRequest.Proxy = null;
            objRequest.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            objRequest.KeepAlive = false; //THIS DOES THE TRICK
            objRequest.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10; // THIS DOES THE TRICK
            objRequest.CookieContainer = CC;

            //http request sending
            using (HttpWebResponse objResponse = (HttpWebResponse)objRequest.GetResponse())
            {
                using (Stream strm = objResponse.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    using (StreamReader objStreamReader = new StreamReader(strm))
                    {
                        htmlPage = objStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
            };
            if (htmlPage.Contains("No results found for") || htmlPage.Contains("(without quotes):") || htmlPage.Contains("Make sure all words are spelled correctly."))
            {
                return dtResult;
            }
            else
            {
                Regex objEgEx = new Regex(@"[\r\n][ ]+\.[\r\n][ ]+");
                htmlPage = objEgEx.Replace(htmlPage, string.Empty);

                int startIndex = htmlPage.IndexOf("<div class =\"g\">");
                if (startIndex == -1)
                { Console.Write("problem in parsing"); }
```

but HttpWebRequest download the first page of the google instead of the url I hd saved for it which is the address of the video search service of Google results' page.
what should I change so that it download the url I want?

Answer (score 1):

You are downloading the page, not the query. Due that the search of google doesn't load a new page but updates a page. Maybe have a look into google search api

Comment: I don't think that google updates the same page because I am exactly sing the same method for text search service and image search service and I can get the results for those services but as I said even though there are parameters in the query string which must lead to creation of new page (or update of the first page of Google) I constantly get the first page of Google and this just only happens for Video.

Comment: also I can't use the google search APIs because I am computing some non functional requirements for the services of the Google (for example the availability) and so I can't use the APIs because if I do that I will compute the statisitcs for the APIs which something that I don't want